# Ways to access element controllers (eg. ngModel & form)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a directive that is always placed inside `<form>` on elements that wrap form elements (`input/select/etc`), let's assume directive is called `wrapper`:

```
<form>
  <something>
    <wrapper>
      <input />
    </wrapper>
  </something>
</form>
```

And from within this directive I need to access both `formController` and `ngModelController`. I know I can `require: ^form` in wrapper's directive definition object, but I still need access to `ngModelController`. I found two ways to achieve it:

```
childFormControl.controller('ngModel')
childFormControl.data('$ngModelController')
// also for controller I could use this, instead of require
childFormControl.closest('form').controller('form')
childFormControl.closest('form').data('$formController')
```

My question is : is it considered a hack to use `controller` or `data` methods to access the controller or is it safe and considered as usage of public **Angular** API? I did not find any examples on **Angular** documentation with this approach.

Comment: You will have access to ngModelController if you add another controller (formController) to your wrapper directive

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="ngModelController ">

<form>
  <something>
    <wrapper>
      <input />
    </wrapper>
  </something>
</form>

</body>
```

Js file

```
(function(){

 var app = angular.module('ngModelController ', function(){
    //Your main controller
  });

 app.directive('wrapper', function(){

    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      controller : function(){
        //Your form controller actions
       },
      controllerAs : 'formController'
    };
 });
})();
```